# Restoring instances of activities in a list?

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is possible to save multiple instances of activities in a list as in when a user selects an item in a listView it opens up its corresponding activity that was activated earlier.

To give you a sense of where I am coming from here is the concept of the app I am making.

In Main Activity there is:

1. A button that when pressed launches a new activity called Exercise
2. A fragment WorkoutsFragment that keeps track of a list of prior workouts.

In Exercise Activity (whose parent activity is main activity):

1. Users can input what exercises they are doing in the activity.
2. When the user goes back to main activity a new item is added to the list in WorkoutFragment and that item contains a summary of the exercises done in the prior Exercise activity. When this item is pressed I want it to go back to the Exercise activity created earlier with all information retained.

So if a user presses the workout item for June 12 I want to to resume the Exercise Activity that was created on June 12.

Would it make more sense to just start a new exercise activity and populate its contents from a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking right. The right way to do it is to create a new Exercise activity and populate its content from database. Maintaining references to activities is not a good practice.
You can also maintain a cache of recent exercises accessed to avoid the database call.

Comment: Would the exercise activity show any noticeable loading when being restored from the database (btw is sqlite a good option?) especially if the exercise activity is slightly more complicated? To give a perspective the exercise activity will have a fragment that holds a listview and a button to add exercises to that list view. Each listview item  contains the exercise, and 1-8 buttons to keep track of reps and timer functionality when a button is clicked.

Comment: You had mentioned MainActivity has the list of WorkOuts.

Comment: Anyways, showing a loader to indicate background operation is recommended. Time taken to fetch data will depend upon the size of the data. In this case, assuming exercise object is small, loading from database should not take much time and can be shown without any loader.

Comment: The main activty has the list of workouts(i think sessions is a better word.)The exercise activty has the list of actually exercises done like squats abs etc. And ok will do thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good case for using the Activity [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

See this guide on restoring different states of an Activity:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

You may pass basic data between your Activities through the Intent [extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()).